# Troubleshooting button need double click to work when first launched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made this code that hides or shows part of the text when you click on a button. However when you first launch the page you need to click two times on the button for it to work. It is only when you first try at the launching of the page because once you have clicked twice you will only need to click once each time like you normally should. Does anyone have any idea on why this is?

Here is my code:

```css
#myDIV {
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#333;
 color:#fff;
 display:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

#myDIV2 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#333;
 color:#fff;
 display:none;
}

#arrow{
 height:10px;
 width:10px;
}

#ok{
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
}

#button{
 background-color:#333;
 color:#fff;
 width:250px;
 empty-cells:hide;
}

table,tr,td{
 border:2px solid black;
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Slides Checkbox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  
  <script> 
   function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
     x.style.display = "none";
    }
   };
   function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
     x.style.display = "block";
    } 
    else {
     x.style.display = "none";
    }
   };
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table id="button">
   <tr>
    <td><button onclick="myFunction()"><img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow"></button>
    Première liste:</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div id="myDIV">
     <ul>
      <li>1er item</li>
      <li>2eme item</li>
      <li>3eme item</li>
     </ul>
    </div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><button onclick="myFunction2()"><img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow"></button>
    Deuxième liste:</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div id="myDIV2">
     <ul>
      <li>1er item</li>
      <li>2eme item</li>
      <li>3eme item</li>
     </ul>
    </div></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <img src="img/ok.png" id="ok">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: On the first click, add a class.  Then add a handler selecting for that class to handle the action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I swapped the if statement around to fix the issue

```js
function myFunction(e) {          
   var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
   if (x.style.display === "block") {
           x.style.display = "none";
   } else {
           x.style.display = "block";
   }
}

function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
     x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
     x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display: none;
}
#myDIV2 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    display: none;
}
#arrow{
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
}
#ok{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
#button{
 background-color:#333;
 color:#fff;
 width:250px;
 empty-cells:hide;
}
table,tr,td{
 border:2px solid black;
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<table id="button">
<tr>
<td><button onclick="myFunction()"><img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow"></button>Première liste:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <div id="myDIV">
      <ul>
      <li>1er item</li>
      <li>2eme item</li>
      <li>3eme item</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button onclick="myFunction2()"><img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow"></button>Deuxième liste:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
   <div id="myDIV2">
   <ul>
      <li>1er item</li>
      <li>2eme item</li>
      <li>3eme item</li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've spent so much hours trying to figure it out. Thank you! My only question is, why is it like that? It doesn't make sense to me logically.

Comment: @AdanVivero looking back at this code the reason for the the logic working on my one is because on the initial load it doesn't pick up the element style, so the css display:none is ignored. Hence why on the first click if statement is false and the second is true which then add the display:block

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when you click for the first time, the if condition on the style for myDiv fails. I added an explicit style attribute to the tag and now it runs perfectly.

For the first button, both consoles log as expected. For the second one, the if condition does not execute.

Note: I only added the style attribute in one of the divs to clarify the difference.

```
enter code here

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Slides Checkbox</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script>    
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
                console.log("1", x.style.display);
                if (x.style.display === "none") {
                    console.log("2");
                    x.style.display = "block";
                } 
                else {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                }
            };
            function myFunction2() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
                console.log("3", x.style.display);
                if (x.style.display === "none") {
                    console.log("4");
                    x.style.display = "block";
                } 
                else {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="button">
            <tr>
                <td><button onclick="myFunction()"><img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow"></button>
                Première liste:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1er item</li>
                        <li>2eme item</li>
                        <li>3eme item</li>
                    </ul>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button onclick="myFunction2()"><img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow"></button>
                Deuxième liste:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div id="myDIV2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>1er item</li>
                        <li>2eme item</li>
                        <li>3eme item</li>
                    </ul>
                </div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <img src="img/ok.png" id="ok">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slides Checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="button">
        <tr>
            <td><button onclick="myFunction()"><img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow"></button>
            Première liste:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="myDIV">
                <ul>
                    <li>1er item</li>
                    <li>2eme item</li>
                    <li>3eme item</li>
                </ul>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button onclick="myFunction2()"><img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow"></button>
            Deuxième liste:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="myDIV2">
                <ul>
                    <li>1er item</li>
                    <li>2eme item</li>
                    <li>3eme item</li>
                </ul>
            </div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <img src="img/ok.png" id="ok">
    
        <script>    
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } 
            else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        function myFunction2() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } 
            else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Hmm, your code seems to do what you desire. The snippet was copied and pasted, and I moved your script to the bottom of  and removed your jQuery links. Could it be your CSS file affecting the initial styling of your page, and your JS taking over after the first initial clicks?

Answer (score 0):

The `HTMLElement.style` property is used to get as well as set the inline style of an element.

When you're calling this block:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} 
    else {
   x.style.display = "none";
}
```

You're checking against the inline display style. Your first click hits the else block and adds `display: none` to the element inline.

To get this to work when you first load, try using the following:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue("display") == "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
```

You'll only have to click once to see your changes applied.